# By what standards is it better to split Kafka partition?

Tags: apache-kafka

I got a few questions while I was preparing the Kafka Service.

First question.
**What is the recommended criterion for partitioning busy services?**
I understand it is a good idea to decide the number of partitions based on the memory of producer and the the consumers.
Are there any criteria to determine the number of partitions?
Your account of the experience will also be of great help.

Second question.
**Sometimes, only one broker happens to be busy during Kafka service.**
How do I fix this?
Is there any way to prevent it?

Question three :
**Is there any way I can know about server dirty shutdown?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the more the partitions in your Kafka cluster the higher the throughput. However, note that there is an (negative) impact of having too many partitions in total on things like availability and latency. [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/) from Confluent can shed some light regarding your first question.

Coming to your second question, a topic is made up of at least one partition. A Kafka broker contains multiple partitions of various topics. Some of these partitions are leaders and some of them are replicas from partitions on other brokers. Therefore, a broker might have some active partitions (leaders) and some inactive (replicas). I guess that in your case, only a single broker contains leader partitions so you need to check your replication and partitioning strategies.

Regarding your last question, you need to consider a Kafka cluster monitoring tool such as [Confluent's Control Centre](https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/), or [Landoop's Kafka LENSES](http://www.landoop.com/kafka-lenses/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: @김태우For kafka cluster monitoring you could also consider Yahoo Kafka Manager which is an open source tool.